# Promisify callback style with optional arguments and run multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I’m trying to [Promisify](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html) with bluebird this function that has an optional second argument (weight) and it’s just not working out whether I try to the do just the method or the whole object.

```
  RateLimit.prototype.incr = function(keys, weight, callback) {
    var args, err, _ref, _ref1;
    if (arguments.length === 2) {
      _ref = [1, weight], weight = _ref[0], callback = _ref[1];
    }
    try {
      _ref1 = this.scriptArgs(keys, weight), keys = _ref1[0], args = _ref1[1];
    } catch (_error) {
      err = _error;
      return callback(err);
    }
    return this["eval"].exec(this.checkIncrFn, keys, args, (function(_this) {
      return function(err, result) {
        return callback(err, __indexOf.call(_this.constructor.DENIED_NUMS, result) >= 0);
      };
    })(this));
  };
```

Original is here (https://github.com/dudleycarr/ratelimit.js/blob/master/src/rate_limit.coffee) but coffeescript so figured this compiled version is a bit more universally readable.

I think a custom promisify would be needed?

Also, my end goal is to have this call in a regression test suite and be able to be run a configurable amount of times with the same keys and weight calling parameters and get an array of the results from each callback in my final callback.

something like this:

```
var runTimes = 5;
var runKey = ‘akey’;
var runWeight = 2;

var keyMap = Array(5).fill(runKey);

Promise.all(Promise.map(keyMap, (k, w) => pPromisifiedIncr(k, w))
.then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
}));
```

I’ve tried combinations of Array().fill().map and Promises.map but was unable to quite get it possibly due to issues with the initial Promisify itself. Thanks!

Comment: promises need one argument, so i'm not sure you can do it exactly like you want...

Comment: Your `incr` requires `keys` and `weight` parameters and a `RateLimit` instance as the context, so I'm not sure what you expect `pPromisifiedIncr(k)` to do?

Comment: You should not promisify `incr` but rather `exec`, and write `incr` in promise style already.

Comment: I'm not the author of incr so that's part of the quandry. I'm looking to learn general techniques for Promisfying when things don't just quite work.

http://ratelimit.io/ is where incr comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hard to see what you're trying to do, but here's an idea that shows a manaully promisified `incr()` and a use of `Promise.map()` to run it through an array of values:

```
RateLimit.prototype.incr: function(keys, weight, callback) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let args;

        // callback argument is optional
        if (arguments.length === 2) {
            callback = weight;
            weight = 1;
        }

        // if this throws, it will automatically reject the promise
        [keys, args] = this.scriptArgs(keys, weight);
        this["eval"].exec(this.checkIncrFn.bind(this), keys, args, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(result.indexOf(this.constructor.DENIED_NUMS) > 0);
            }
        });
    });
}


var keys = [{weight: 1, key: 'akey1'}, {weight: 2, key: 'akey2'}, {weight: 3, key: 'akey3'}, {weight: 4, key: 'akey4'}];

Promise.map(keys, item => xxx.incr(item.key, item.weight)).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
```

I can't say I follow all the details of what your `.incr()` function is trying to do or how it translates to straight Javascript, but this should give you a general idea of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If the `.incr()` method already works (and especially if it's part of a third party library that you're incorporating into your project), your best option would probably be to leave it the way it is, and create a separate method for the the promise version, in which case it's rather easy:

```
RateLimit.prototype.incrPromise = function(keys, weight) {
    var self = this;
    var args = arguments;

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var callback = function (err, result) {
            if(err) { reject(err); } else { resolve(result); }
        };

        self.incr.apply(self, Array.prototype.concat.call(args, callback));
    });
};
```

To use it:

```
var runTimes = 5;
var runKey = ‘akey’;
var runWeight = 2;

var keyMap = Array(5).fill(runKey);
var myRateLimit = new RateLimit(); // create RateLimit here    

Promise.all(Promise.map(keyMap, (k, w) => myRateLimit.incrPromise(k, w))
    .then((values) => {
        console.log(values);
    }));
```